# What is wrong with the first tikz-page? There is a xshift of a few mm

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a strange problem with the first page of a series of pages, drawn by the same function.

I have to admit that i don't really understand the difference between macros and variables and length and so on but the code works - in principle.

The content of page 1 is shifted to the right - only on page 1 - the following pages seem very ok.

Could somebody explain?

Kind regards
Peter

(the file is the drawing of Curiosity Show's Knitting Needle Filing System...)

```
\documentclass[a5paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\geometry{a5paper,
 left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
 landscape
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newlength{\width}
\newlength{\xspace}
\newlength{\xoff}
\newlength{\yspace}
\newlength{\csize}
\newlength{\height}
\newlength{\ydelta}
\setlength{\width}{210mm}
\setlength{\height}{148mm}
\setlength{\csize}{5mm}
\setlength{\xspace}{40.25mm}
\setlength{\yspace}{11mm}
\setlength{\xoff}{.5\width}
\addtolength{\xoff}{-1.5\xspace}
\setlength{\ydelta}{\height}
\addtolength{\ydelta}{-\yspace}
\def\ybitset{\ydelta+\height*.5-\ydelta*.5}

\newcommand{\checkpos}[2]{%
  \StrMid{#1}{#2}{#2}[\testchar]
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\testchar}{\string 0}}
    {\def\bitcol{white}}
    {\def\bitcol{black}}%
}

\newcommand{\knfs}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
\checkpos{#1}{1}
\node[rectangle, fill=\bitcol!25, draw=none, minimum width = \csize, minimum height = \yspace] at (\xoff+\xspace*0, \ybitset) {};
\checkpos{#1}{2}
\node[rectangle, fill=\bitcol!25, draw=none, minimum width = \csize, minimum height = \yspace] at (\xoff+\xspace*1, \ybitset) {};
\checkpos{#1}{3}
\node[rectangle, fill=\bitcol!25, draw=none, minimum width = \csize, minimum height = \yspace] at (\xoff+\xspace*2, \ybitset) {};
\checkpos{#1}{4}
\node[rectangle, fill=\bitcol!25, draw=none, minimum width = \csize, minimum height = \yspace] at (\xoff+\xspace*3, \ybitset) {};
\node[circle, fill=black!25, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=\csize] at (\xoff+\xspace*0,\ydelta) {};
\node[circle, fill=black!25, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=\csize] at (\xoff+\xspace*1,\ydelta) {};
\node[circle, fill=black!25, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=\csize] at (\xoff+\xspace*2,\ydelta) {};
\node[circle, fill=black!25, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=\csize] at (\xoff+\xspace*3,\ydelta) {};
\node[draw=none, fit={(0,0) (\width,\height)}, inner sep=0pt, label={[yshift=-20]center:{\fontsize{280}{0}\selectfont #2}}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\knfs{0001}{1}\\
\knfs{0010}{2}\\
\knfs{0011}{3}\\
\knfs{0100}{4}\\
\knfs{0101}{5}\\
\knfs{0110}{6}\\
\knfs{0111}{7}\\
\knfs{1000}{8}\\
\knfs{1001}{9}\\
\knfs{1010}{10}\\
\knfs{1011}{11}\\
\knfs{1100}{12}\\
\knfs{1101}{13}\\
\knfs{1110}{14}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
After some experimenting to obtain a back shift I did a simple `\hspace*{-5.2mm}\knfs{0001}{1}\\` on the first page...the result is not exact - but maybe good enough. But the question remains...

Comment: `\noindent\knfs{0001}{1}` worked for me and removed the page indent.

Comment: The issue is that the first line is being indented since it is the start of a "paragraph". As @LaccaseTVersicolor commented, `\noindent` fixes the issue.

Comment: Further to @SandyG's comment, in the future @texpiet if you have weird spaces or indention try `\noindent` at the place it is occurring and ensure that all your commands have the appropriate `%` at the end of the lines (I checked your `checkpos` command first with added `%`), that's what I try first when I am debugging.

Comment: Thank you all! That solved it. That is a true newbie error... @LaccaseTVersicolor, maybe you can answer this to give U the credit, since U were first.

Comment: I will answer it so that the community bot doesn't keep bumping this to the top of the feed every few months, I am glad it solved your issue, yeah I am still in the newbie phase too so it's no worries, at least you know for the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `\knfs{0001}{1}` to `\noindent\knfs{0001}{1}` so that the page indent is removed.

Updated code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\geometry{a5paper,
 left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
 landscape
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newlength{\width}
\newlength{\xspace}
\newlength{\xoff}
\newlength{\yspace}
\newlength{\csize}
\newlength{\height}
\newlength{\ydelta}
\setlength{\width}{210mm}
\setlength{\height}{148mm}
\setlength{\csize}{5mm}
\setlength{\xspace}{40.25mm}
\setlength{\yspace}{11mm}
\setlength{\xoff}{.5\width}
\addtolength{\xoff}{-1.5\xspace}
\setlength{\ydelta}{\height}
\addtolength{\ydelta}{-\yspace}
\def\ybitset{\ydelta+\height*.5-\ydelta*.5}

\newcommand{\checkpos}[2]{%
  \StrMid{#1}{#2}{#2}[\testchar]
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\testchar}{\string 0}}
    {\def\bitcol{white}}
    {\def\bitcol{black}}%
}

\newcommand{\knfs}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
\checkpos{#1}{1}
\node[rectangle, fill=\bitcol!25, draw=none, minimum width = \csize, minimum height = \yspace] at (\xoff+\xspace*0, \ybitset) {};
\checkpos{#1}{2}
\node[rectangle, fill=\bitcol!25, draw=none, minimum width = \csize, minimum height = \yspace] at (\xoff+\xspace*1, \ybitset) {};
\checkpos{#1}{3}
\node[rectangle, fill=\bitcol!25, draw=none, minimum width = \csize, minimum height = \yspace] at (\xoff+\xspace*2, \ybitset) {};
\checkpos{#1}{4}
\node[rectangle, fill=\bitcol!25, draw=none, minimum width = \csize, minimum height = \yspace] at (\xoff+\xspace*3, \ybitset) {};
\node[circle, fill=black!25, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=\csize] at (\xoff+\xspace*0,\ydelta) {};
\node[circle, fill=black!25, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=\csize] at (\xoff+\xspace*1,\ydelta) {};
\node[circle, fill=black!25, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=\csize] at (\xoff+\xspace*2,\ydelta) {};
\node[circle, fill=black!25, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=\csize] at (\xoff+\xspace*3,\ydelta) {};
\node[draw=none, fit={(0,0) (\width,\height)}, inner sep=0pt, label={[yshift=-20]center:{\fontsize{280}{0}\selectfont #2}}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\knfs{0001}{1}\\
\knfs{0010}{2}\\
\knfs{0011}{3}\\
\knfs{0100}{4}\\
\knfs{0101}{5}\\
\knfs{0110}{6}\\
\knfs{0111}{7}\\
\knfs{1000}{8}\\
\knfs{1001}{9}\\
\knfs{1010}{10}\\
\knfs{1011}{11}\\
\knfs{1100}{12}\\
\knfs{1101}{13}\\
\knfs{1110}{14}
\end{document}
```